# python lock misunderstanding

Tags: python

I feel difficult to understand the following multi-thread synchronization code and hope someone can point out where my misunderstanding is.

```
import threading

cond = threading.Condition()
class user(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, cond,no):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.cond = cond
        self.no = no

    def run(self):
        self.cond.acquire()

        print(self.no + '_1')
        self.cond.notify()
        self.cond.wait()

        print(self.no + '_2')
        self.cond.notify()
        self.cond.wait()

        self.cond.release()


user1 = user(cond,'user1')
user2 = user(cond,'user2')
user1.start()
user2.start()
```

The running result is:

```
user1_1
user2_1
user1_2
user2_2
```

According to my understanding, the two thread should be in a deadlock situation because user1 acquire the 'cond' and wait for user2's notification at 'self.cond.wait()' while user2 is blocked at 'self.cond.acquire()' and can't reach 'self.cond.notify()'. It seems like they are all blocked and waiting for the other one to give them what they need, so they should be in a deadlock situation.

Where is my misunderstanding about the lock?

Answer (score 0):

Your program works as it is supposed to work. There is no deadlock, as `Condition.wait()` releases the lock, allowing user2 to acquire it and proceed.